# Manifest is not valid JSON. Line: 1 , column 1, Unexpected token error

Tags: javascript, visual-studio, google-chrome-extension, manifest, manifest.json

I'm trying to load an unpacked manifest.JSON file into Chrome extensions, but I keep getting the error: Manifest is not valid JSON. Line: 1, column: 1, Unexpected token. I've attached the coding and any help would be much appreciated!

```
{
    "name": "Starred Apps",
    "description": "save and star important websites, like bookmarks but cleaner",
    "version": "1.0",
    "manifest_version": 3,
    "background": {
      "service_worker": "background.js"
    },
    "permissions": ["storage"]
  
  }
```

and I'm not sure if this matters, but here is the background.js file

```
let color = "#3AA757";

chrome.runtime.onInstalled.addListener(()=> {
chrome.storage.sync.set({color});
console.log('Default background color set to ${color}');
});
```

Comment: What's the unexpected token?

Comment: @evolutionxbox I have no idea...

Comment: Resave the file in UTF8 encoding without BOM.